# Get Position from modal Google map in Razor view

Tags: javascript, asp.net, razor, bootstrap-modal

I'm writing an MVC project that includes the possibility to add points in a Google map. So far I can add points to db by hardcoding latitude and longitude values, but I want to let the user select the position on the map and send them back to the controller from the Razor view.
I have already written part of the view and I'm able to open a modal popup with the map and a hardcoded location.
What I want to do is:
1. let the user insert an address in a textbox
2. open the modal popup and have the map centered with a marker near the address
3. save back the position in two fields of the view in order to send them back to the controller.

I have been using the code provided by Google Developers at:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/place-details
and have come to the following code:

All the code is in the Razor View:

```
    <form>
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Ubicazione: </legend>


            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Indirizzo, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" style="float:left"
                            data-toggle="modal" data-target="#findInModal" data-backdrop="static"
                            data-keyboard="true" data-address='pippo'>
                        Trova posizione
                    </button>
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Indirizzo, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" }, @id="addr" })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Indirizzo, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>


            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Latitudine, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @*@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Latitudine, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })*@
                    @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Latitudine, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Latitudine)
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Latitudine, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Longitudine, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @*@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Longitudine, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })*@
                    @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Longitudine, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Longitudine)
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Longitudine, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>
        </fieldset>
    </form>
```

I would like the value of the **data-address='pippo'** to be the address in the **"@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Indirizzo …."**

Here is the modal popup content that opens the map and centers it to a hardcoded position:

```
    <!-- Find Location In Modal -->
    @using (Html.BeginForm())
    {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()


        <div class="modal fade" id="findInModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
            <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <h5 class="modal-title" style="height: 0px;"></h5>
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Chiudi">
                            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">


                        <div id="gMap" style="height:400px;width:100%;"></div>
                        <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=APIKEY&language=it&region=IT&libraries=places&callback=gMap" async defer></script>
                        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
                        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
                        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
                        <script>

                            let myCenter;
                            let mapProp;
                            let map;
                            let service;

                            function gMap() {
                                myCenter = new google.maps.LatLng(41.893140, 12.483330);
                                mapProp = { center: myCenter, zoom: 15, scrollwheel: true, draggable: true, mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID };
                                map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("gMap"), mapProp);




                                let request = {
                                    query: 'Musei Capitolini',
                                    fields: ['name', 'geometry'],
                                };

                                service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);

                                service.findPlaceFromQuery(request, function (results, status) {
                                    if (status === google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
                                        for (let i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
                                            createMarker(results[i]);
                                        }

                                        map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
                                    }
                                });
                            }
                            function createMarker(place) {
                                let marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                                    map: map,
                                    position: place.geometry.location,
                                    icon: "/Content/icons/01.png"
                                });
                                google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
                                    infowindow.setContent(place.name + place.geometry.location);
                                    infowindow.open(map, this);
                                });
                            }
                        </script>

                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Chiudi</button>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Salva</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    }
```

and here is the script that open the popup:

```
    <script>

        $('#findInModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
            let button = $(event.relatedTarget) // Button that triggered the modal
            let AddressToFind = button.data('address') // Extract info from data-* attributes
            // If necessary, you could initiate an AJAX request here (and then do the updating in a callback).
            // Update the modal's content. We'll use jQuery here, but you could use a data binding library or other methods instead.
            let modal = $(this)
            modal.find('.modal-title').text('Find near: ' + AddressToFind)


        })

    </script>
```

At the moment I have not implemented how to return the **place.geometry.location** values to the parent view, but they are suppose to update the **model => model.Latitudine** and **model => model.Longitudine** values that will be returned to the controller to update the db.

Thank in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No help from devs, but going deep into the Google Developers documentation and testing it at JSFiddle, I finally came out with the following solution:

```
@model GoogleMapTest.Models.MapPoint

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
}

<h2>Create</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <fieldset>
        <legend>MapPoint</legend>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Address)
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Address)
                @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Address, new { id = "Address" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Address)
            </div>

            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" style="float: left"
                data-toggle="modal" data-target="#findInModal" data-backdrop="static"
                data-keyboard="true">
                Find Position
            </button>

        </div>


        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Latitude)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Latitude)
            @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Latitude, new { id = "Latitude" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Latitude)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Longitude)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Longitude)
            @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Longitude, new { id = "Longitude" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Longitude)
        </div>

        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Create" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}


<!-- Find Location In Modal -->
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()


    <div class="modal fade" id="findInModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h5 class="modal-title" style="height: 0px;">Set Point in Map</h5>



                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <input id="pac-input" class="controls" type="text" placeholder="Find...">

                    <div id="gMap" style="height:400px;width:100%;"></div>
                    <script src="https://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&key=AIzaSyDMD8_QumYpomzDTcHW-myppqsyCZRsnB8"
                                // APIkey end with call to libraries "&libraries=places&callback=initAutocomplete"
                            async defer></script>

                    <script>


                        function initAutocomplete() {
                            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('gMap'), {
                                center: { lat: 41.893321, lng: 12.482929 },
                                zoom: 13,
                                mapTypeId: 'hybrid',
                                scrollwheel: true,
                                zoomControl: false,
                                scaleControl: true,
                                streetViewControl: false,
                                fullscreenControl: false,
                                mapTypeControl: false
                            });

                            // Create the search box and link it to the UI element.
                            var input = document.getElementById('pac-input');
                            var searchBox = new google.maps.places.SearchBox(input);
                            map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(input);

                            // Bias the SearchBox results towards current map's viewport.
                            map.addListener('bounds_changed', function () {
                                searchBox.setBounds(map.getBounds());
                            });

                            var markers = [];
                            // Listen for the event fired when the user selects a prediction and retrieve
                            // more details for that place.
                            searchBox.addListener('places_changed', function () {
                                var places = searchBox.getPlaces();

                                if (places.length == 0) {
                                    return;
                                }

                                // Clear out the old markers.
                                markers.forEach(function (marker) {
                                    marker.setMap(null);
                                });
                                markers = [];

                                // For each place, get the icon, name and location.
                                var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
                                places.forEach(function (place) {
                                    if (!place.geometry) {
                                        console.log("Returned place contains no geometry");
                                        return;
                                    }

                                    // create infowindow: just while debugging not needed in View
                                    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

                                    // create geocoder for address
                                    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

                                    // Create a marker for each place.
                                    markers.push(new google.maps.Marker({
                                        map: map,
                                        //icon: "/Content/icons/01.png",
                                        title: place.name,
                                        position: place.geometry.location,
                                        draggable: true
                                    }));

                                    // Add listeners to marker:
                                    // click: opens infowindow
                                    markers[0].addListener('click', function () {
                                        infowindow.open(map, markers[0]);
                                        infowindow.setContent(place.name + ': ' + place.geometry.location);
                                        infowindow.open(map, this);

                                        // Add listeners to map
                                        google.maps.event.addListener(markers[0], 'dragend', function (evt) {
                                            infowindow.setContent('Lat: ' + evt.latLng.lat() + '       Lng: ' + evt.latLng.lng());
                                            infowindow.open(map, this);

                                            map.setCenter(markers[0].getPosition());
                                            markers[0].setMap(map);
                                            map.setTilt(0);
                                            map.setZoom(20);

                                            // update return values
                                            // gLat, gLong, gAddr are global variables
                                            gLat = evt.latLng.lat();
                                            gLong = evt.latLng.lng();

                                            // get address
                                            var latlng = { lat: parseFloat(gLat), lng: parseFloat(gLong) };
                                            geocoder.geocode({ 'location': latlng }, function (results, status) {
                                                if (status === 'OK') {
                                                    if (results[0]) { gAddr = results[0].formatted_address } else {
                                                        gAddr = 'NotFound';
                                                    }
                                                }
                                            });

                                        });

                                    });

                                    if (place.geometry.viewport) {
                                        // Only geocodes have viewport.
                                        bounds.union(place.geometry.viewport);
                                    } else {
                                        bounds.extend(place.geometry.location);
                                    }
                                });
                                map.fitBounds(bounds);
                            });

                        }



                    </script>

                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Chiudi</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="updFields(gLat, gLong, gAddr)">Salva</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}



<script>

    $('#findInModal').on('show.bs.modal', function () { 
    })

    function updFields(lat,lng, addr) {
        //alert('Lat: ' + lat + '\nLng: ' + lng + '\nAddr: ' + addr);
        //document.getElementById("Address").value = addr;
        //document.getElementById("Latitude").value = lat;
        //document.getElementById("Longitude").value = lng;
        $('#Address').val(addr);
        $('#Latitude').val(lat);
        $('#Longitude').val(lng);
    }

</script>
```

*infowindow* and *alerts* are just in while developing, but are not part of the final solution.

Basically I implemented a Google Maps Search Box with the Autocomplete and Place service, and a Geocoder to retrieve the address from the coordinators.To this I added a function that updates my hidden fields.The code of the view is much more complex because it contains other fields not relevant to the position in the map and makes it possible to manually modify the fields, but basically this is the backbone of the code.

I would have like to post images, it seem that my APIkey has overgone quota.